# Java return nested type parameters

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I have a problem with Java's Generic System.
In my program is a wrapper for lists, that should have a method to return it's inner list:

```
public class Wrapper<T, S extends List<T>> {

    private S list;

    public Wrapper(S list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public S get() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then there is a Context that holds a Map with different Wrappers and a method that returns the list of the wrapper associated with the id:

```
public class Context {

    private Map<String, Wrapper> map;

    public Wrappers() {
        map.put("a", new Wrapper(ArrayList<String>());
        map.put("b", new Wrapper(LinkedList<Integer>());
    }

    public <T, S extends List<T>> S getList(String id) {
        return map.get(id).get();
    }
}
```

Now when I call getList() I want to have a compiler warning or at least a way to realise an error before a ClassCastException gets thrown.

```
public class Receiver {

    public doSomething() {
        Context c  = new Context();
        c.createWrappers();

        // Ok
        ArrayList<String> list1 = c.getList("a");
        LinkedList<Integer> list2 = c.getList("b");

        // Compiler error or some way do check in getList().
        ArrayList<Integer> list3 = c.getList("a");
        LinkedList<String> list4 = c.getList("b");
    }
}
```

I've actually tried a lot of things like changing the Wrapper definition to:

```
public class Wrapper<T, S extends List>
```

But when I want to implement the get() function I run into a problem I can either define the function like this:

```
public List<T> get() {
    return list;
}
```

or like this

```
public S get() {
    return list;
}
```

In the first example it would still be possible to do this.

```
public doSomething() {
    //...
    LinkedList<String> list = c.getList("a");
}
```

and in the second example it would be possible to do this.

```
public doSomething() {
    //...
    ArrayList<Integer> list = c.getList("a");
}
```

Is there any way to define the get method in a way like this?

```
public S<T> get() {
    return list;
}
```

It seems to me like there is no way to check both the type of the list and the type of the elements at the same time.

Comment: Why are you using generics that at all? Your list always has the same type; you should return that type.

Comment: Sorry I  tried to clean up my question and removed too much. The wrapper should be able to hold different Lists as well. I'll improve my question right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler has no way of knowing what return type is associated with the particular string you passed (strings cannot be made type-safe).

However, you could replace strings with type-safe marker objects:

```
class ListId<T> {
    public ListId(string name) { ... }

    public static final ListId<ArrayList<String>> A = new ListId<>("a");
    public static final ListId<LinkedList<Integer>> B = new ListId<>("b");
}

public T getList<T>(ListId<T> id)
```

Comment: But wouldn't this mean, that I can only save one ArrayList<String> wrapper. Could I also use an enum as the key?

Comment: @superuser: No; you can have multiple keys with the same type.  No; enums do not support type parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much this has given me quiet some headache.